# Angular 6 production build "Can't bind to 'disabled' since it isn't a known property of 'div'"

Tags: angular

My app seems to work when using the JIT compiler, but when I attempt to use AOT compiler using `ng build --prod` then it throws an error:

`ERROR in : Can't bind to 'disabled' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("[ERROR ->]<div formButton></div>")`

How do I figure out where this error is coming from?

I just added lazy loaded feature modules instead of importing everything in the `app.module.ts` and I don't know if I need to import `FormButtonComponent` into the feature modules?

I've searched through the codebase and I can't find any instances where `formButton` is on anything but a `button`.

Here's `button.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, HostBinding, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from "@angular/core";

/**
 * Button with loading and disabled states
 */
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: '[formButton]',
    templateUrl: 'button.component.html'
})
export class FormButtonComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input() loading? = false;
    @Input() disabled? = false;
    @HostBinding('disabled') disabledAttribute = false;

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        this.updateState();
    }

    updateState(): void {
        this.disabledAttribute = this.disabled || this.loading;
    }
}
```

`button.component.html`

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
<spinner [size]="small" *ngIf="loading"></spinner>
```

Here's a few example calls from other places in my app:

`<button formButton [loading]="template.loading" [disabled]="disabled" class="button" type="submit">Design</button>`

`<button formButton class="button" [loading]="form.disabled" (click)="save()">Change Password</button>`

`<button formButton [ngClass]="buttonClass" (click)="upload()" [loading]="uploaderWrapper.isUploading">{{ buttonText }}</button>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit:  I talked with one of the Angular team members and this is caused by the fact that my selector didn't specify an element.  So when building with `ng build --prod` angular uses `div` as the "lowest common denominator":

> the error you see refers to  because divs are the lowest common
>   denominator of HTML element. If a component selector doesn't specify
>   any other element type, then it becomes a div.

So there are two solutions:

1) make the selector more specific so that it only tries to AOT compile with an element that has the `disabled` property.

Update `selector: '[formButton]'` to `selector: 'button[formButton]'`

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'button[formButton]',
    templateUrl: 'button.component.html'
})
```

2) update to use `attr.disabled` instead of `disabled`.  The downside to this is that you have to then use `value | null` instead of `true | false` because browsers look for the presence of the `disabled` attribute and not what it's value is.

`@HostBinding('disabled') disabledAttribute = false;`

to

`@HostBinding('attr.disabled') disabledAttribute = false;`

with this template:

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
<spinner [size]="small" *ngIf="loading"></spinner>
```

Comment: Can you upload zip with copy of folder?

Comment: Just adding attr. before the disabled worked for me, didnt change the selector. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ITs saying you that somewhere in your code you have `<div formButton></div>` search your code and remove it

Comment: If you read the question then you'll see that I already said that I've searched my code for that element and it does not exist.

Comment: @DeniseMauldin stupid suggestion but i would search even inside of node_modules

Comment: @DeniseMauldin second suggestion try to change selector to anything like  selector: '[myFormButton]', it could be conflict with someother libs,