# Disable in directive do not reset

Tags: javascript, angular, directive

Following this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-skqonk)

I have a Directive that, when you click, it should disable the button until a certain time (to prevent double click).

```
<button appThrottleClick (throttleClick)="click()">
  BUTTON
</button>

<button appThrottleClick [disabled]="myValue" (throttleClick)="click()">
  BUTTON VALUE
</button>
```

I would like the button to disable and then be re enable after x seconds. Using this directive here :

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[appThrottleClick]'
})
export class ThrottleClickDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    @HostBinding('attr.disabled') disabled: boolean;

    @Input() throttleTime = 200;

    @Output() throttleClick = new EventEmitter();

    private clicks = new Subject();
    private subscription: Subscription;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.subscription = this.clicks.pipe(
            throttleTime(this.throttleTime)
        ).subscribe(e => {
            this.throttleClick.emit(e);
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    clickEvent(event) {
        console.log('click')
        if (this.disabled) { return; }
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        this.disabled = true;
        this.clicks.next(event);
        setTimeout(() => { this.disabled = false; console.log('reset')}, this.throttleTime);
    }
}
```

Basically :

If the button is not disabled, click once, then put a cooldown and reenable it again.
If the button is disabled, do not click.

The problem I face, after clicking, and waiting the cooldown, it is never reenabled again. Even tho disabled is set to false.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `@HostBinding` us `ElementRef` to disable and enable the button so your directive will be

```
import { Directive, EventEmitter, HostListener, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit, Output, HostBinding,ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { throttleTime } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Subject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appThrottleClick]'
})
export class ThrottleClickDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    @Input() throttleTime = 1000;

    @Output() throttleClick = new EventEmitter();

    private clicks = new Subject();
    private subscription: Subscription;

    constructor(private _elementRef:ElementRef) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.subscription = this.clicks.pipe(
            throttleTime(this.throttleTime)
        ).subscribe(e => {
            this.throttleClick.emit(e);
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    clickEvent(event) {
        console.log('click')
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        this._elementRef.nativeElement.disabled=true; 
        this.clicks.next(event);
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log('reset')
           this._elementRef.nativeElement.disabled=false; 
           }, this.throttleTime);
    }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dedutp)

Comment: I saw a lot on internet that this is not necessary, and using HostBinding should be enough to make it work. Any reason why in this case I must use elementRef ?

Comment: well there are two reason 1. host binding is not working as you specified about 2.Angular will create a binding for that element and that means extra checking if property change or not.In that way angular is checking if something is changed if so then apply the change and continue the same thing while in case of element ref we are doing it by our self and angular is having no overhead of taking care of that extra property

Comment: ok thank you. also, the solution is ok, but It doesn't care about the current [disable] binding if it's set and used or not.

Comment: @Bobby just set disabled='true' and remove hostbinding  demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rbyjuq

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`disabled`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50798552/4051471) instead of `attr.disabled` while using `HostBinding` in your `ThrottleClickDirective`, [stackblitz sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l5wtx3?embed=1&file=src/app/throttle.directive.ts):

```js
...
export class ThrottleClickDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    @HostBinding('disabled') disabled: boolean;

    @Input() throttleTime = 200;
...
```

**EDIT:** You could use th element reference as a work around to check the `nodeName` property to use the directive appropriately if the directive need to be used with other elements as well:

```js
...
    constructor(private element: ElementRef) { }
...
        this.clicks.next(event);
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (this.element.nativeElement.nodeName == "DIV")
            this.disabled = false;
          else if (this.element.nativeElement.nodeName == "BUTTON")
            this.element.nativeElement.removeAttribute('disabled');
          console.log('reset')
        },
        this.throttleTime);
...
```

Comment: the problem I have with `@HostBinding('disabled') disabled: boolean;` is that the app says `Can't bind to 'disabled' since it isn't a known property of 'div'` everywhere I use the directive. I saw on the internet that to fix this we had to use attr.disabled

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50382710/angular-6-production-build-cant-bind-to-disabled-since-it-isnt-a-known-prop